# Oracle - Concatenate Field on Where

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, where-clause

I'm using a Concatenate Field and I'd like to use it on the WHERE of it

```
TABLE T_EXAMPLE
RED - FERRARI - F50
BLUE - PORSHE - S20  
GREEN - CAMARO - T40
```

I have to show all this fields on a Grid, 'cause of this that I need to put all of them in one field, but I have to filter the Grid with One information that can be any one of the three, example:

```
SELECT
  T.COLOR || T.CAR,T || T.Model AS FIELD1
FROM T_EXAMPLE T
WHERE FIELD1 LIKE '%FER%'
```

Here I want to filter the Ferrari, but I've tried to do like this but I got an error (Invalid Identifier).

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alias `FIELD1` can't be used in the `WHERE` clause, so just repeat the column concatenation in the `WHERE` clause. Like this:

```
SELECT
  T.COLOR || T.CAR || T.Model AS FIELD1
FROM T_EXAMPLE T
WHERE T.COLOR || T.CAR || T.Model LIKE '%FER%'
```

Or, if you don't like the repetition, another option would be this:

```
SELECT FIELD1
FROM (
  SELECT
    T.COLOR || T.CAR || T.Model AS FIELD1
  FROM T_EXAMPLE T
)
WHERE FIELD1 LIKE '%FER%'
```